# Closed-form integrals for $e^{f(x)}$

Tags: calculus

For what smooth functions $f(x)$ is there a "nice" closed-form expression for
$$ \int_0^a e^{f(x)} \mathrm{d}x$$
More specifically, I am looking for $f$ such that if 
$$ b = \int_0^a e^{f(x)} \mathrm{d}x, $$
then the right-hand side may be inverted so that $a$ may be written in terms of $b$.

I am aware of the cases where

- $f$ is constant
- $f$ is linear
- $f = \ln(g(s))$, where the integral of $g$ is "nice"

Comment: Well, for $f(x) =-x^2$ there is none.

Comment: Doesn't quite answer my question, but yes

Comment: Yes, silly of me.

Comment: this also doesn't answer your question, but linear functions are not positive.

Comment: I realized I don't need positivity anymore

Comment: My time spent in complex analysis allowed me to overcome some pretty wonderful complex integrals using Jordan's lemma, viz,

\begin{align}
\int_0^\pi e^{-r \sin \theta} \leq \frac{\pi}{r}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to find a lot of functions $f(x)$ :

Chose an arbitrary differentiable function $F(x)$. Compute it's derivative $F'(x)$
$$f(x)=\ln\left(F'(x)\right)$$
This function $f(x)$ is likely to be an answer to the question.

EXAMPLE :

$F(x)=e^{x^2} \quad\to\quad F'(x)=2xe^{x^2} \quad\to\quad 
f(x)=\ln\left(F'(x)\right)=\ln\left(2xe^{x^2}\right)$

$$f(x)=x^2+\ln(2x)$$

$b=\int_0^a e^{f(x)}dx = \int_0^a e^{x^2+\ln(2x) }dx = \int_0^a 2xe^{x^2}dx =e^{a^2}-1$

$a=\sqrt{\ln(b+1)}$

Of course, this method appears as a gimmick : just taking the problem in reverse.